# JavaScript document.createElement() within Object

Tags: javascript, object, createelement

I think I'm having another dumb moment. I've looked around for the past half hour, but Google searches aren't returning anything useful. I can't find the words to describe the issue I'm having. Here's my code.

```
function myElement(){

    this.init = function(){
        this.display();
    }

    this.display = function(){
        var element = document.createElement("div");
    }   
}

var myElement = new myElement();
myElement.init();
```

The issue I'm having is that the code (`.createElement("div")`) isn't working. I've messed around with it, and I've tried using other things too (such as JQuery's `$.create('<div></div>');` method).

I'm not entirely sure if it's a scope or referencing issue.

(Please be aware that it's 02:10AM in the morning. My brain isn't in its most active state.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append the element to something, like another element, or the body.

```
 document.body.appendChild(element)
```

Comment: This will fail with an error, `myElement` is not a DOM element.

Comment: I thought this would work when I first saw your answer, but technology has other ideas. :(

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null`

Comment: document.body.appendChild() is the method that adds elements to the body. Pass it your new element. So: document.body.appendChild(element)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've done. I'm familiar with how object/methods/classes work, but I'm relatively new to JavaScript. Is there anything else that could be causing the error?

Comment: Ahh, never mind. I moved my code to the bottom of the page, and now it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is working, but you're not doing anything with the div. I'm guessing you want to append it to the DOM:

```
this.display = function(){
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(element);
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I would've accepted it, but MazeHatter got the same answer, just seconds before yours, therefore I've accepted his.

+1 for including the whole function though, it's tidy. :D